# Problemas con máscara no me deja escribir

Tags: java, poo, eclipse, herencia, interfaz

Tengo una interfaz para registrar usuarios necesito usar uan máscara para verificar que se cumple el formato que pide por ejemplo para nombre que sea una String, pero a la hora de escribir los datos en la interfaz no me deja escribir anda, si quito la máscara si, adjunto mi código y una imagen de la interfaz.

```
private void init() throws ParseException {
    this.jlbNombre = new JLabel("Nombre");
    this.jlbNombre.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 20);
    this.add(jlbNombre);

    this.jlbCedula = new JLabel("Cedula");
    this.jlbCedula.setBounds(10, 40, 100, 20);
    this.add(jlbCedula);

    this.jlbNumTelefono = new JLabel("Num. Telefono");
    this.jlbNumTelefono.setBounds(10, 70, 100, 20);
    this.add(jlbNumTelefono);
    
    //En esta parte agrego la máscara
    this.mascaraNombre = new MaskFormatter(new String());
    this.jftNombre = new JFormattedTextField(mascaraNombre);
    this.jftNombre.setBounds(100, 10, 100, 20);
    this.add(jftNombre);

    this.jftCedula = new JFormattedTextField();
    this.jftCedula.setBounds(100, 40, 100, 20);
    this.add(jftCedula);

    this.jftNumTelefono = new JFormattedTextField();
    this.jftNumTelefono.setBounds(100, 70, 100, 20);
    this.add(jftNumTelefono);

    this.jbtnCancelar = new JButton("Cancelar");
    this.jbtnCancelar.setBounds(10, 100, 90, 25);
    this.jbtnCancelar.addActionListener(this);
    this.add(this.jbtnCancelar);

    this.jbtnRegistrar = new JButton("Registrar");
    this.jbtnRegistrar.setBounds(120, 100, 90, 25);
    this.jbtnRegistrar.addActionListener(this);
    this.add(this.jbtnRegistrar);

} // Init
```

Los otros espacios a los que no les he agregado la máscara si los puedo llenar pero este no.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Una máscara no se usa para verificar que el valor sea String, eso ya viene dado. Te recomiendo que veas la documentación sobre MaskFormatter

Comment: te agradecería si me adjuntaras el link, gracias y en este caso para el número de teléfono que es un entero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para utilizar un MaskFormatter es necesario que de manera explicita escribas la cadena que respetará la máscara, por ejemplo "###-####":

```
MaskFormatter formatter = new MaskFormatter("###-####");
```

la cual aceptará el formato "999-9999"

si quieres saber que mas caracteres puedes usar para la mascara, la documentación la encuentras en esta liga

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/MaskFormatter.html